# When Veda Vyasa divided the Vedas, didn't he write them somewhere?

Tags: vedas, vyasa

As the question says, when Veda Vyasa divided the Vedas into 4, didn't he write them somewhere? Did he write manuscripts about them?

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism SE. Can you please elaborate your question to explain whether you wanted to ask about the 4 vedas or the original combined Veda in some manuscript form.